# Deploy Firebase Cloud-Function with Node Canvas fails on Mac M1

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-canvas

I just got a new Mac M1 and i am trying to deploy a Firebase Cloud Function. It works fine, as long as I do not include the node canvas module.

When I try to deploy, i am getting the following error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: dlopen(/Library/WebServer/Documents/inklay_web_cf/functions/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node, 0x0001): tried: '/Library/WebServer/Documents/inklay_web_cf/functions/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/canvas.node' (no such file), '/usr/lib/canvas.node' (no such file)
    at tryImporting (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1736:37)
    at process.dlopen (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1762:5)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1186:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1024:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1338:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/inklay_web_cf/functions/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1136:30)
vonnielu@lukass-macbook-pro-1 functions % node-gyp rebuild
zsh: command not found: node-gyp
```

It seems, that Firebase Cloud Function does not like the architecture. But what can I do? Any help is very welcome.

Node: v16.14.0
Firebase Tools: 10.2.0
Mac OS Monterey: 12.2.1
Apple M1 Max

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by:

- Downgrading node version to v12.22.10
- Delete all node_modules in my projects folder
- Run rosetta terminal in vs-code
- npm install
- Delete my cloud functions (Deploy with all functions uncommented)
- Deploy my cloud functions (firebase deploy)

Answer (score 0):

late answer: facing the same type of issue with an Apple M1 chip (arm64 architecture), I found why my node version was involved:

- my problem would show up for even a minor node version change, which was varying depending on the tool/editor I was using (took me weeks of hair pulling)
- the different node versions installed were compiled for different processors architecture: 16.3.0 was x86_64, 16.15.0 was arm64. Eventually one had been installed before I changed the machine from an x86 based to an arm64 based (I transferred my backups, maybe, and the next version was brought up or compiled for my new architecture
- canvas somehow was systematically x64_64, so compatible only with an x86_64 node install

I'm now looking at 2 options for resolution, either I'm using the previous node in x64, or I find how to get canvas for arm64 / local arch systematically in my package.json (the clean way, imho). (3rd way: new node on x64 but not clean either)